# MySQL 8.0 dynamic SQL returns column name instead of column value

Tags: mysql

Using MySQL 8.0, have written stored procedure (SP) having Dynamic SQL and result is collected in a View.  However, when SP is executed, it just returns column names not the column values. SP source code is given below.

```
drop procedure if exists dynamic_cursor;
delimiter //

CREATE PROCEDURE dynamic_cursor (IN table_name  VARCHAR(40),
                             IN key_name    VARCHAR(40),
                             IN column_name VARCHAR(40),
                             IN before_date DATETIME,
                             IN curr_key    VARCHAR(40))
BEGIN
DECLARE done INT DEFAULT 0;
DECLARE v_key_name VARCHAR(40);
DECLARE v_column_name varchar(50);
DECLARE out1 VARCHAR(100);
DECLARE out2 VARCHAR(100);
DECLARE cur CURSOR for( SELECT key_name, column_name from past_shpt_view);
DECLARE CONTINUE HANDLER FOR NOT FOUND SET done = 1;

DROP VIEW IF EXISTS past_shpt_view;

SET @sqlstr = "CREATE VIEW past_shpt_view as ";
SET @sqlstr = CONCAT(@sqlstr , " SELECT ", key_name,",", column_name);
SET @sqlstr = CONCAT(@sqlstr , " FROM ", table_name);
set @sqlstr = concat(@sqlstr,  " where rec_cre_dt_utc < '");
set @sqlstr = concat(@sqlstr,   before_date,"'");
set @sqlstr = concat(@sqlstr, " and shipment_num = '");
set @sqlstr = concat(@sqlstr,  curr_key, "'");
set @sqlstr = concat(@sqlstr,' order by rec_cre_dt_utc desc LIMIT 1');

PREPARE stmt FROM @sqlstr;
EXECUTE stmt;
DEALLOCATE PREPARE stmt;

OPEN cur;
FETCH cur INTO v_key_name, v_column_name;

SELECT   v_key_name, v_column_name;

CLOSE cur;

END;
//
delimiter ;
```

Any idea what could be the issue. Have spent a whole of time on this. Please help.

Comment: When you debug your code, what is the resulting SQL statement being executed?

Comment: Is this really what your procedure is doing, or have you simplified it to ask this question? As far as I see, there is no purpose or benefit to using a view or a cursor in this procedure.

Comment: This code is chock full of extremely concerning SQL injections.

Comment: Hi,  Thanks  to you all.  It's working at last, removed the cursor variable declaration and related statements.